# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘devtools’ came up when loading devtools package

Tags: r

I successfully installed the `devtools` package, but when I wanted to load the package, this error came up:

```
library(devtools)

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘devtools’ in
loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =
vI[[j]]):  namespace ‘cli’ 3.0.1 is already loaded, but >= 3.1.0 is
required In addition: Warning message: package ‘devtools’ was built
under R version 4.1.2
```

Comment: Please don't post images of text error messages. It makes it tougher to find and search for help for future users. Just copy/paste the text into your question. Try restarting R and running `install.packages("cli")`. It looks like the library was loaded by something else and therefore could not be properly updated. Restarting R should unload that package.

Comment: Restart your R session should do the trick